# Encode/decode C-string literals

Tags: python, replace, escaping, cstring

I have a text file containing something that behaves like C-strings. For example:

```c
something = "some text\nin two lines\tand tab";
somethingElse = "some text with \"quotes\"";
```

Fetching things between quotes is not a problem. Problem is that later I'm processing this string and slash escapes makes this hard.

I'd like to decode these strings, process them, then encode them back to C-string literals.

So from that raw input

```
some text\\with line wrap\nand \"quote\"
```

I need:

```
some text\with line wrap
and "quote"
```

and vice versa.

**What I've tried**:

I've found [some API](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_encode.htm) for processing [Python string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) (`string_escape`), it is close to what I need, but since I'm processing C-strings it is useless. I've tried find other codecs to match my problem but no luck so far.

Comment: You're dealing with escape sequences, not text encoding. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences

Comment: `json.dumps` encodes Unicode characters to`\u<someCode>` and this doesn't work for me :/.

Comment: OK loolks like `json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=False)[1:][:-1]` do the work nicely, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a simple solution also, and `json` module seems to be the easiest solution.  The following is my quick hack.  Note that there are still issues if/when **both** the single (') and double quote (") appear in the same string... **And** I suspect you will have issues with unicode characters...

```
def c_decode(in_str:str) -> str:
    return json.loads(in_str.join('""' if '"' not in in_str else "''"))

def c_encode(in_str:str) -> str:
    """ Encode a string literal as per C"""
    return json.dumps(in_str)[1:-1]
```

Note also that if `in_str` is `"AB\n\r\tYZ"` ...

```
then we alternatively have: ("%r"%(in_str.join('""')))[2:-2]
giving: 'AB\\n\\r\\tYZ' # almost the same c_encode above.
```

Here's hoping that *someone* has a nicer solution.